# Multivariate linear mixed model using glmer in R package lme4 - inconsistent error between updates

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, multivariate-testing

I am trying to run a multivariate linear mixed model and need to use a remote workstation to reduce compute time.

When I run glmer() from lme4 on my personal computer (R version 2.15.1, lme4 version 0.999999-0, 64 bit Unix) my model runs appropriately.

When I switch to the remove workstation (R version 3.0.2, lme4 version 1.0-6, 64 bit Linux) my model does not run and I receive an error and a warning message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : updateMu: Size mismatch
In addition: Warning message:
  calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly
```

Interestingly, if I run lmer() on either of the dependent variables, the model will run without error or warning.

Here is sample code:

```
library(lme4)

DV.1 <- rnorm(100,2,0.3)
DV.2 <- rnorm(100,5,2)
FE.1 <- sample(c(1:3),100,replace=TRUE)
FE.2 <- sample(c(1:2),100,replace=TRUE)
RE.1 <- rep(c(1:10),10)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(DV.1,DV.2,FE.1,FE.2,RE.1))

glmer(cbind(DV.1,DV.2)~FE.1+FE.2+(1|RE.1),family=gaussian,data=df)
```

Here is output from my personal computer:

```
> glmer(cbind(DV.1,DV.2)~FE.1+FE.2+(1|RE.1),family=gaussian,data=df)
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: cbind(DV.1, DV.2) ~ FE.1 + FE.2 + (1 | RE.1) 
   Data: df 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 76.94 89.97 -33.47    53.66   66.94
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 RE.1     (Intercept) 0.00000  0.00000 
 Residual             0.10322  0.32128 
Number of obs: 100, groups: RE.1, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  2.02330    0.13377  15.125
FE.1        -0.04980    0.04082  -1.220
FE.2         0.06238    0.06451   0.967

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr) FE.1  
FE.1 -0.626       
FE.2 -0.719 -0.037
```

Here is output from the remote workstation with a newer version of lme4:

```
> glmer(cbind(DV.1,DV.2)~FE.1+FE.2+(1|RE.1),family=gaussian,data=df)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : updateMu: Size mismatch
In addition: Warning message:
In glmer(cbind(DV.1, DV.2) ~ FE.1 + FE.2 + (1 | RE.1), family = gaussian,  :
  calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly
>
```

I am wondering if the model is formed incorrectly, or if there is a complication with one version of lme4.
Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand your model.  I'm quite surprised that you can get away with passing a two-column matrix as the response: as far as I know the only *documented* use of anything other than a numeric vector response is for binomial data.  If you want to do multivariate analysis, as far as I know you have to use the approaches mentioned [here](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/3336).  (You should also probably use `lmer()` instead of `glmer(...,family="gaussian")`)